# "Bearer of good news" & "bearer of bad news" are called?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

> The person who brings a good(good news messenger) news is called ? similarly the person who
>   brings the bad news(bad news messenger) is called ?

In this generation that may be same person. But earlier(in ancient times during Kings) they had different people for such tasks. Thus one would get the good one and other would being the bad news.

I am looking for a single word that describes good news bearer and bad news bearer. OR a common word for both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. What did you find out through your research?

Answer (score 4):

A *[harbinger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/harbinger)* foretells:

> noun
>
> 1. A person or thing that announces or signals the approach of another:
>
> *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: Welcome to ELU Wicliffe, I have added some features to your answer to improve it. You can add these features to your future answers.

Answer (score 3):

In English, I don't know of such two words distinguishing good and bad.

But there is one word for the one who brings news or "bears tidings" and that is

> messenger

as in "Don't shoot the messenger." (presumably in the case they bring *bad* tidings).

Answer (score 2):

An "evangelist" is--at least etymologically--a bearer of good news; and I suppose a "dysangelist" or "kakangelist" (if such words exist) or something similar would be a bearer of bad news.  But the common meaning of "evangelist" has changed considerably from mere "bearer of good news" to a technical religious term.

Answer (score 1):

A Jonah or hoodoo or jinx is a person or thing that brings bad luck.

A boon or godsend implies a very helpful or valuable event, person, or thing.

However, an envoy brings you news and only after then can it be the bearer of bad or good news. He can also be called a messenger.

Comment: An "evangelist" is--at least etymologically--a bearer of good news; and I suppose a "dysangelist" (if such a word exists) or something similar would be a bearer of bad news.  But the common meaning of "evangelist" has changed considerably from mere "bearer of good news".